# Android Proguard issue with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am an Android developer, I am using Gradle to build my projects, if I use Proguard I get an IOException that says:

```
Execution failed for task ':ProjectName:proguardRelease'.
java.io.IOException: Can't write [:***\build\inter mediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar] (Can't read [:***\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android\MSFPush\1.1.6\libs\support -v4-19.1.0.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/suppo rt/v4/app/p.class == support-v4-19.1.0.jar:android/support/v4/app/FragmentState. class]))
```

Please help, how do I solve the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

in build.gradle, exclude the entity causing the duplicates issue:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
  }
```

Comment: Hi Robert as told by you I tried excluding the entity causing duplicates but still I get the same issue.